# Relacionar dois dataframes utilizando lógica em python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Olá, necessito relacionar os dois dataframes abaixo utilizando como condições (i) se 'cat' do df1 está na tupla da coluna 'cat' do df2; e (ii) a coluna 'evento'. O resultado deveria ser uma coluna 'resp' no df1 que contem os respectivos dados na df2.

Abaixo deixo os exemplos de dataframes que se assemelham ao original:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nome': ['João', 'Maria', 'Antonio', 'Pedro', 'João', 'Maria', 'Antonio', 'Pedro'],
    'cat': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'evento': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'sim/não': ['sim', 'não', 'sim', 'sim', 'não', 'sim', 'não', 'sim']
   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat': [('A', 'B'), ('C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C')],
    'evento': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'resp': ['sim', 'não', 'não', 'não']
   })
```

O dataframe final deveria ficar assim:

```
df_resultado = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nome': ['João', 'Maria', 'Antonio', 'Pedro', 'João', 'Maria', 'Antonio', 'Pedro'],
    'cat': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'evento': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'sim/não': ['sim', 'não', 'sim', 'sim', 'não', 'sim', 'não', 'sim'],
    'resp': ['sim', 'sim', 'sim', 'não', 'não', 'não', 'não', 'não']
   })
```

Pensei em utilizar o método "merge" da seguinte forma:

```
df_resultado = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['evento', 'cat'])
```

Contudo, com essa lógica a coluna 'resp' no df1 fica com valores nulos para as 'cat' A e B, já que o método analizou as tuplas que estão em df2.

Poderiam, por gentileza, me indicarem a sintaxe para fazer essa relação corretamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) resolve isso:

```
>>> df_resultado = df1.merge(df2.explode("cat", ignore_index=False), how='left', on=['evento', 'cat'])

>>> df_resultado
      Nome cat  evento sim/não resp
0     João   A       1     sim  sim
1    Maria   A       1     não  sim
2  Antonio   B       1     sim  sim
3    Pedro   C       1     sim  não
4     João   A       2     não  não
5    Maria   A       2     sim  não
6  Antonio   B       2     não  não
7    Pedro   C       2     sim  não
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.